# Nuxt cannot change data variable

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I usually use vue, in nuxt variable x in data, and method to change this data x, but in html changes not reloaded.

example :

>

```js
export default {
  data () { 
    return { openPopup: '1' }
  },
  
  methods: {
    changeData() {
        this.openPopup = 2;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<template>
  <span>
     {{openPopup}}
  </span>
  <button @click="changeData()">change</button>
</template>
```

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings on the dev tools console? I can't get it to compile the template with multiple root elements. Try wrapping the two elements in your template with a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from openPopup in your data. It is being treated as a string.

```
data () { 
    return { openPopup: 1 }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong in other place. Your code is working fine ( if u fix multiple root elements ).

here it is on codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/yqxxkpyw61